# Using JS or JQuery, move all in a selection from one list to "selected" using jQuery's listselect.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a struts select section in a jsp file that becomes a standard HTML select:

```
        <s:select
            id="selectedTillsSelectId"
            name="selectedTillsSelectName"
            cssClass="tillDropDownEntryList"
            list="tillDropDownEntryList"
            listKey="key"
            listValue="value"
            value="%{selectedTills}"
            />
```

turns into

```
<select name="selectedTillsSelectName" id="selectedTillsSelectId" class="tillDropDownEntryList">
  <option value="1">0001</option>
  <option value="2">0002</option>
  <option value="3">0003</option>
  <option value="4">0004</option>
  <option value="5">0005</option>
  <option value="6">0006</option>
  <option value="7">0007</option>
  <option value="8">0008</option>
</select>
```

My understanding is that struts merely populates the list, and it can be forgotten that struts is involved from that point.

This then is displayed as a split list

```
All              Selected
0001             
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
```

Thanks to some listselect jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/js/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/js/jQuery/listselect.js"/>"></script>
```

This is all pre-existing working code I've been asked to amend. When you click on an individual item on the left, it moves into the "selected" column on the right. Clicking 0003 results in:

```
All              Selected
0001             0003
0002
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
```

**I have been tasked with adding a button that moves everything over to the selected column, a "Select all" button.**

I have added the button and this works ok, but I can't get it to do what I want. I can get the options into a list, and I can "select" them iteratively - but all this does is highlight the entry. I want to actually move the entry to the second column. Any attempts at calling click on the list items doesn't do anything or isn't valid, I've tried every permutation I can find in suggestions online, which may become apparent when you see the current state of my "select all" function: (please bear in mind, I've kept the commented out versions mostly to help remind me what I've tried, but I think they'll give a good indication to what I've had a go at)

```
function selectAllTills() 
{
//    alert("Select all the Tills..."); 
    var bothLists = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var unselectedList = bothLists[0];
    var selectedList = bothLists[1];
    var allOptions = unselectedList.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i=0; i < allOptions.length; i++) {
//            allOptions[i].selected = true;
//      allOptions[i].attr('selected', 'selected');
//      allOptions[i].selected = true;
//      $("#selectedTills").val(i).attr("selected","selected");
//      alert("allOpions is" + allOptions[i]);
//      selectedList.val(allOptions[i]);
      $("#selectedTillsSelectId").val(allOptions[i]);
    }

//    $("#selectedTillsSelectId").find("option").appendTo(".tillDropDownEntryList"); //tried based on nnnnnn's suggestion

//    $("div#tillSelectionDiv select option").each(function(){
//        $(this).attr("selected","selected");
//      $(this).trigger("click");
//      $(this).click();
//      alert($(this));
//    });

}
```

I guess it's at this point I confess to not really working with javascript much at this point. I'm a java programmer so understand OOP and I can read most of what I've seen in the page and it makes sense. Firebug suggests that the items I'm iterating over are HTMLElementOption which sounds about right, and using jQuery supposedly I can call "click" on the element but that didn't work... As mentioned above, iterating and setting selected *did* work in selecting the item, but it just makes the item blue on the left rather than moving it over, which I guess would be fine if this was a standard dropdown and not the jQuery listselect.

Any assistance greatly received, if I've missed anything, please let me know in the comments so I can amend the question.

Many thanks,
Mitch.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.jquery-az.com/a-jquery-multi-select-list-view-plug-in-with-six-options/ I have not tried it yet, but it looks very cool.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the listselect.js does things, but to literally move all of the option elements from the first select to the second you can do it with one line of jQuery. Just put the following in whatever function you call when the "move all" button is clicked:

```
$("#selectedTillsSelectId").find("option").appendTo("#idOfSecondSelectHere");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AHn7Z/

I'm assuming the second select element has an id that you can include in the `.appendTo()`.

Comment: Gj =] Gtk i doesn't know appendTo. Ty

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn - unfortunately no, there is only one select element, the one at the top of the OP. The list of selected items is maintained (I think/assume) somewhere in with the reference tillDropDownEntryList

Comment: I think you'll find that listselect.js probably has some method(s) that will let you do what you're trying to do - check its documentation. But in any case there must be a second select element even if it is created by the JS code, so you could access it some other way, e.g., if you know there are only two selects on the page you can access the second one like this: `$("#selectedTillsSelectId").find("option").appendTo("select:eq(1)")`.

Comment: Thank you. I've looked at the documentation I can find, but to no avail. I have also tried what you suggested but with no luck. I imagine there may well be other "hidden" selects, or it seems it is possible perhaps that the display of the list is overridden in CSS which I am also investigating, though that doesn't help me with the selection. - Thanks again!